# Populate a form from a select list

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have tried multiple attempts at populating a report from selecting a value in a select list.  I have come close but not close enough for the right answer.  Does anyone have a solution?

Here is the code

Currently I have a select list that has the option of choosing an employees track and the employees track is populated in the select list based on :app_user.

#### List of Values

List of values definition:

```
SELECT track_name AS display_value,
       track_id   AS return_value
FROM   ref_track
ORDER  BY 1
```

Source Value for select list:

```
SELECT "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_NAME" AS display_value,
       "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_ID"   AS return_value
FROM   "REF_STAFF",
       "REF_PLAN",
       "WORK_ITEM",
       "REF_RELEASE",
       "REF_TRACK"
WHERE  "REF_RELEASE"."RELEASE_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."RELEASE_ID"
       AND "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID"
       AND "WORK_ITEM"."WR_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."WORK_ITEM_ID"
       AND Nvl("REF_STAFF"."REF_STAFF_TRACK_ID", "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID") =
           "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID"
       AND (( "REF_STAFF"."STAFF_USER_ID" = :APP_user ))
```

I now have a report beneath it that is being populated when the page loads that also generates data based on `:App_user`.

Report Source Code:

```
SELECT "REF_PLAN"."PLAN_ID"             "PLAN_ID",
       "REF_PLAN"."WORK_ITEM_ID"        "WORK_ITEM_ID",
       "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID"            "TRACK_ID",
       "REF_PLAN"."PLANNED_TOT_HRS"     "PLANNED_TOT_HRS",
       "REF_PLAN"."PLAN_START_DATE"     "PLAN_START_DATE",
       "REF_PLAN"."PLAN_END_DATE"       "PLAN_END_DATE",
       "REF_PLAN"."COMMENTS"            "COMMENTS",
       "REF_PLAN"."RELEASE_ID"          "RELEASE_ID",
       "WORK_ITEM"."WR_ID"              "WR_ID",
       "WORK_ITEM"."WR_NUM"             "WR_NUM",
       "REF_RELEASE"."RELEASE_ID"       "RELEASE_ID2",
       "REF_RELEASE"."RELEASE_NUM"      "RELEASE_NUM",
       "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_ID"           "TRACK_ID2",
       "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_NAME"         "TRACK_NAME",
       "REF_STAFF"."REF_STAFF_TRACK_ID" "REF_STAFF_TRACK_ID",
       "REF_STAFF"."STAFF_USER_ID"      "STAFF_USER_ID"
FROM   "REF_STAFF",
       "REF_PLAN",
       "WORK_ITEM",
       "REF_RELEASE",
       "REF_TRACK"
WHERE  "REF_RELEASE"."RELEASE_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."RELEASE_ID"
       AND "REF_TRACK"."TRACK_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID"
       AND "WORK_ITEM"."WR_ID" = "REF_PLAN"."WORK_ITEM_ID"
       AND Nvl("REF_STAFF"."REF_STAFF_TRACK_ID", "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID") =
           "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID"
       AND (( "REF_STAFF"."STAFF_USER_ID" = :APP_USER ))
       AND "REF_PLAN"."TRACK_ID" = :P47_TRACK_LIST
```

I tried adding this line to pick from the select list.

Is there any way to manipulate this code to be able to select a track from my list and populate data based on the track selection in my report.  I would also like to let you know that my select list values are based on a submit page.  Please let me know if you can help me.  Its frustrating when I look at something for a complete day and cant figure the code out.  Also, if there is any other way around it or other options to explore please let me know.

Comment: Please attach the code you have tried so far

Comment: I have edited my original question to add the code.  Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the report to update when you change the selected value of the select list, you can do this in 2 ways. But both come down to the same principle: your selected value has to be submitted to the session state in order for the report to filter on it.

Solution 1: have the select list submit/redirect the page. This will submit the value of your select list to the session, and reloads the page. With the redirect you will fill up the browser history though: select a value a couple of times, and you use 'back' on the browser to navigate back through the choices you made. Or use a submit, this'll reload the page too, but won't fill the history as much. There'll still be one extra history entry though (initial, and first reload, following reloads are not in history).

Find the option by editing your select list, going to the Settings region, and change the page action when value changed.

[image: select list options]

Solution 2:  refresh the report region through a dynamic action. This will not reload the page, it'll 'refresh' just your report. This might be the most userfriendly, it depends if you like a page reload or not :)
You'll need a dynamic option, configured like this:
[image: dynamic action details]

With these true action details:

[image: dynamic action true action details]

And most important, to make sure your selected value is submitted to the session state: add the item to the list of items to be submitted when the report is refreshed.
[image: items to submit on report refresh]

I set up an example [here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:12)